# Generating dll file from object files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, object, dll

When I want to generate a shared object (.so) in unix os from object files, I simply enter following command:

> g++ -shared xxx.o yyy.o zzz.o -o module.so

I am wondering if I can do the same thing in windows in order to generate a .dll file from object files. Is that possible?

Comment: This might help,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705501/how-do-i-compile-a-cpp-source-file-into-a-dll?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have MinGW32 or Cygwin installed, then yes. But you can't do it using Visual Studio directly, since Visual Studio uses the `cl` compiler driver which has an entirely different set of options.

Comment: so in this way, can I create my dll file in unix os and use it in windows?? I mean for example>>>> g++ -shared x.o y.o z.o -o module.dll >>>> in unix shell and then I use module.dll file in windows?

Comment: No, your Unix OS and Windows use a totally different executable format, standard library and even calling convention. You'd have to use a cross compiler on Unix (and I'm not aware of any current Windows-targeting cross compilers for Unix OSes besides MinGW). You're best off compiling Windows DLLs on Windows.