# .DLL oads from an .EXE but not a .DLL

Tags: python, c++, dll, exe

I need to convert an .exe file to a .dll so I can load it into Python with ctypes. Inside my program, I call another DLL. Currently, the program runs fine if it is executed in an .exe and when I compile it as a DLL, there are no error messages.

However, when I compile as a DLL, load this into Python, and call the main function, the DLL I call inside my function is not loaded. I don't understand why this is... Is it not possible to call a DLL from a DLL? Alternatively, if there were an issue with the path, wouldn't the DLL fail to load in the .exe file?

Comment: the best way is to put all the DLLs in the same directory...

Comment: Are you calling LoadLibrary on the second DLL from withing your own DLL? Maybe post a more concrete example of what you're doing so we can see.

Comment: You can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705501/how-do-i-compile-a-cpp-source-file-into-a-dll

Comment: You should not call main function manually, call one of the exported c functions instead.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! I think the issue was calling the dll from the dll main function.